# TouchableOpacity hangs inside ListView when I am using navigation in onPress method

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am using ListView, each Item of ListView is TouchableOpacity  component. onPress I need to navigate to another page. So onPress method I call _navigator(). But when I press on Item (TouchableOpacity element) its hangs on several seconds about 4-5s. Here an example of my code.

```
    rerenderRow(row, rowID, tabId) {
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.element} onPress={() => this._navigate('NewPage', row)}> 
        <View>----</View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    }
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you show some more of the code, including the `_navigate` method

Comment: Thank you Nader. Here short version of my cod https://jsfiddle.net/eczdpw1y/

Comment: @NaderDabit     Here short version of my cod jsfiddle.net/eczdpw1y

Comment: I can't run the code on jsfiddle. For React Native there is rnplay.org, can you provide a link please?